# Multiple loading in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, loading

On my page, I have 3 dropdowns that are taking data from the API and I need 3 loadings for each one of them.

```
const {loading, error, watchMakes } = watchMakeList;
const {loading, error, watchModels } = watchModelList;
const {loading, error, watchSize} = watchSizeList;
```

But I cannot do it like this because I am getting an error that says Identifier 'loading' has already been declared. So can you give me an idea to fix this issue and use the loading in multiple places?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the renaming of those loading and error variables like this:

```
const {loading: makeListLoading, error:makeListError, watchMakes } = watchMakeList;
const {loading: modeListLoading, error: modeLsitError, watchModels } = watchModelList;
const {loading: sizeListLoading, error: sizeListError, watchSize} = watchSizeList;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can assigning to new variable names like this:

```
const {loading: makeLoading, error, watchMakes } = watchMakeList;
const {loading: modeLoading, error, watchModels } = watchModelList;
const {loading: sizeLoading, error, watchSize} = watchSizeList;
```

Answer (score 0):

try assigning `loading` to a new variable name. It's not a feature in React. It's Javascript Destructuring.

```js
const {loading: newVariableOne, error, watchMakes } = watchMakeList;
const {loading: newVariableTwo, error, watchModels } = watchModelList;
const {loading: newVariableThree, error, watchSize} = watchSizeList;
```

https://wesbos.com/destructuring-renaming is a good resource about this topic.